# Line break inside DataFrame's column's name

Tags: python, pandas, export

My understanding would be that have line break `\n` as part of a string that represents a column of a `pandas.DataFrame` can be considered *bad-practice*. For example:

```
pandas.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]], columns=['First\ncolumn', 'Second\ncolumn'])
```

The main reason is that, this masks the columns name behind cumbersome names and thus, error-prone. One of the advantages however, is that when exporting the `DataFrame`, to excel for instance, this can be handy in terms of formatting the columns' names.

What would be considered a *best-practice* in this case? Is there a way to format the columns only for the exporting? I couldn't find one.

Answer (score 2):

#### Remove newline in columns names

In order to get red of the **"new line"**, **"\n"**, **"line break"** inside pandas dataframe column names, just use the line of code bellow :

```
df.columns = [x.replace("\n", " ") for x in df.columns.to_list()]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `header` parameter:

```
>>> df = pandas.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]], columns=['First_Column', 'Second_Column'])
>>> df.to_csv('/tmp/df.csv', header=['First\nColumn','Second\nColumn'])
>>> pandas.read_csv('/tmp/df.csv') 
   First\nColumn  Second\nColumn
0              1               2
1              3               4
```

Comment: From my little experiment the `columns` option in the exporting function can help you choose a subset of the columns to be exported, but it won't actually rename the columns. Can you please clarify?